# MySql if distinct print true

Tags: mysql, if-statement, distinct

I am trying to write a sql statement that will print the id and true if it is distinct false if not.  Here is my query

```
Select Id, IF(Id IS DISTINCT('True', 'False')) from Table;
```

Comment: what do you mean with "if is distinct"  .?   .. this term have no sense  to me .... .show a sample of data and the expected  result

Comment: Probably test that the aggregate `COUNT() = 1` , but please clarify your requirement with a sample set of input rows and a sample of the desired query output.

Comment: if it's an ID, it should be distinct already. if it allows dupes, it wouldn't be much of an ID...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you looking for exactly. But if it is a rowset indicating if the Id you have is unique or not, this may help:

```
SELECT
  Id,
  case when (select count(Id) from Table where id = T.id)=1 then 'True' else 'False' End As 'isunique'
FROM
  Table T
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you re-write your query to be like

```
Select distinct Id, 'True' as optional_col from Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id
     , case when count(*) < 2 then 'True' else 'False' end as isunique  
  from mytable
group by id;
```